# Laravel - condition on belongsTo relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I use Laravel 5.6, I have 3 Models :

- Area
- Store
- Merchant

**Area** has many **Stores** :

```
public function stores()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Beproxy\App\Models\Store');
}
```

**Store** belongs to one **Merchant** :

```
public function merchant()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Beproxy\App\Models\Merchant');
}
```

In my **Merchant**, I have one tinyInt to define if the Merchant is active or not (*state*)

Can I write a new function in my **Area** Model to get all **Stores** which belong to an active **Merchant** ?

With *hasMany* relation, I can use :

```
public function storesWithProducts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Store')->has('products');
}
```

But I don't find how to use a condition for *belongsTo*, I tried in my **Area**, but it loads everything :

```
public function storesWithMerchantActive()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Store')
        ->with(['merchant' => function($query) {
            $query->where('state', '=', 1);
        }])
        ->has('products');
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to use another relation for this. You could utilize whereHas on the storesWithProducts and check for a merchant that is active as shown below:

```
public function storesWithMerchantActive()
{
    return $this->storesWithProducts->whereHas('merchant', function ($query) {
        $query->where('state', 1);
    })->get();
}
```

Comment: Nice one, I thought `with` would have done the same.

Answer (score 7):

I think you just need to update this function may help.

```
public function merchant()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Beproxy\App\Models\Merchant')
    ->where('state','1');
}
```